# How to use backslash in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

I have an 'Execute SSIS Package' activity in my ADF, that requires from me passing the parameter for Environment. In my case the paramater value is `.\Dev`. Unfortunately, the dot - backslash sentence is required by SSIS.

I am trying to provide the parameter dynamically, but every time my value `.\Dev` is being changed to `.\\Dev` (Each backslash is doubled inside Azure Data Factory). I have tried different solutions like looking up the parameter in the database or setting a variable and even replacing double backslash with single one, but it didn't work - every time I should get `.\Dev` i was getting `.\\Dev`. It also looks like this double backslash is treated as one character by ADF (in case of replace or substring functions).

Can anyone help with that?

Comment: and what error are you getting? looks like ADF is trying to automatically escape the especial characters, have you tried modifying the pipelien JSON definition code? and hard-coding the environment-value there without the double backslash?